# calculating lot size to recover lost pips using a fixed TP value?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

If I have let say 100 pips total loss on multiple trades , and I want to recover that 100 pips loss by opening a new trade which has 30 pips TakeProfit, how do I calculate the Lot size for this new trade, so that when the TP of 30 pips is hit , it will recover the loss which was incurred (100 pips loss)?

Comment: You can't really express a monetary loss in pips, you need to know the lot size for each individual trade/loss to calculate this.

Answer (score 0):

If X lots = 100pips, first determine how many X lots will 30pips equivalent to 100pips.

Numbers of lots = X(100/30) or 0.33X lots size.